# Meaning of "ggf." in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Montageklammern nicht entfernen ggf. ist eine Wiederverwendung durch den Mieter vorgesehen.

How would you understand the use of *ggf.* in this context? They may be reused by the tenant?

Comment: There's nothing special in this context. Same meaning as always.

Comment: @Em1: While it's the same meaning as always, it actually would be hard for a non-native to understand this sentence due to the missing comma. Again, this is indeed nothing special, since lots of people make comma mistakes. But while both your assertions are true, let's at least try not to give a new member the feeling she's asking a stupid question.

Comment: @Mac Fair enough. That could the crux of the matter. – However, what certainly missing is that she (apparently) knows the general meaning of "ggf" as stated in a comment to an answer only. At any rate, the question urgently needs an amendment.

Answer (score 6):

ggf. = gegebenenfalls = if applicable, if necessary, where required, as the case may be

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know the meaning of the phrase, but I don't exactly see how it is working in the middle of the sentence like that (aside from ggf. there doesn't seem to be any connecting word between the two clauses but I'm not familiar with ggf. as a connecting word).

Comment: @Jacqueline: It's two sentences, there is a comma or semicolon missing after entfernen. Furthermore, you should edit this (what exactly your issue is) into your question.

Comment: There's a comma missing after _entfernen_.

Comment: One could also use "unter Umständen" in this context, if you prefer a German synonym. And yes, there is a comma/semicolon missing...

Answer (score 0):

> How would you understand the use of ggf. in this context? They may be
>   reused by the tenant?

Yes, I would understand it like this. Don't remove it/throw it away as the (next) tenant may want to use it.

However, for me *ggf.* sounds strange in combination with *vorgesehen*. I would say:

> Die Montageklammern bitte nicht entfernen, da eine Wiederverwendung (der Montageklammern) durch den Mieter vorgesehen ist.

or

> Die Montageklammern bitte nicht entfernen, um eine Wiederverwendung (der Montageklammern) durch den Mieter zu ermöglichen.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence looks like a common formal written statement and as you suspected the meaning is "may be reused". In the strict sense I see two problems here (that might be the reason for your question):

1. This is **not a sound sentence** from a grammar point of view. Rather something like an extended infinitive ("Montageklammern nicht entfernen") and a real sentence ("Ggf. ist eine Wiederverwendung durch den Mieter vorgesehen.") appended to it.
2. In my opinion the term *gegebenenfalls* has **actually a slightly different meaning** than what it is used for in the example. I would use it like "if this is case" or "if this is applicable" (see following example).

> Geht ihr Flug nach Tel Aviv, dann ist mit besonderen Wartezeiten zu rechnen. Wir empfehlen ggf. eine Stunde früher am Flughafen zu sein.

Comment: I don't see a difference in meaning between your example and the one in the question. Frankly speaking, I think in both sentences (yours and in the question) the use of "ggf" is actually not a good choice.

Comment: And the question's example *is* quite a sound sentence. There's just a comma missing. And the verb is not the best choice.

Comment: I disagree with both of your objections. 1. Infinitives for giving instructions are _very_ common, they are used almost like imperatives. 2. _Gegebenenfalls_ can also just mean _possibly_.

Comment: What I wanted to suggest is using ggf. as "wenn das der Fall ist" or "in diesem Fall".

Comment: Can it be a sound sentence when there is a comma missing, Em1? Maybe I am too formal?

Comment: This is a minor mistake, pretty harmless. Should've been fixed in the very beginning, actually. Now it's too late. But your answer implies that there are severe issues. There aren't. So, yes. Even with a missing comma, a sentence can be considered sound. ("Sound" is defined as "in good condition", not "perfect".)

Comment: Em1, I accept your different view on that.